# How to ensure the integrity of data sent to the database from my application?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database, jailbreak, data-integrity

I am currently creating an iOS application with Swift. For the database I use Firebase Realtime Database where I store among other things information about the user and requests that the user sends me.
It is very important for my application that the data in the database is not corrupted.
For this I have disabled data persistence so that I don't have to store the requests locally on the device. But I was wondering if it was possible for the user to directly modify the values of the variables during the execution of my application and still send erroneous requests.
For example the user has a number of coins, can he access the memory of the application, modify the number of coins, return to the application and send an erroneous request without having to modify it himself.
If this is the case then is it really more secure to disable data persistence or is this a misconception?
Also, does disabling access to jailbroken devices solve my problems? Because I've heard that a normal user can still modify the request backups before they are sent.

To summarize I would like to understand if what I think is correct? Is it really useful to prevent requests to save locally or then anyway a malicious user will be able to modify the values of variables directly during the execution and this without jailbreak?

I would also like to find a solution so that the data in my database is reliable.

Thank you for your attention :)

PS : I also set the security rules of the db so that only a logged in user can write and read only in his area.

Answer (score 1):

You should treat the server-side data as the only source of truth, and consider all data coming from the client to be suspect.

To protect your server-side data, you should implement Firebase's server-side [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security). With these you can [validate data structures](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security#section-validation) and [ensure all read/writes are authorized](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security#section-authorization).

Disabling client-side persistence, or write queues as in your previous question, is not all that useful and not necessary once you follow the two rules above.

---

As an added layer of security you can enable Firebase's new [App Check](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check), which works with a so-called attestation provider on your device (DeviceCheck on iOS) to detect tampering, and allows you to then only allow requests from uncorrupted devices.

By combining App Check and Security Rules you get both broad protection from abuse, and fine-grained control over the data structure and who can access what data.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
But, from what I've seen from a previous post, a user who hasn't tampered with their phone can still modify the requests before it is sent. And in my example, instead of sending a request with 100 pieces can send one with 10,000. 
So the security rules I put in will not prevent that corrupted request from being executed.
Also, I don't know if without a jailbreak or special root, a user can directly modify my variables (which I will send in the request) during the execution of my application but if so what good would App Check do me ?